# Who is Denny Crane supposed to be in the costume party in S03e13?

Tags: character, boston-legal

In *Boston Legal* episode 13 of Season 3 "Dumping Bella", there's a costume party at the end of the episode. Denny Crane comes dressed in some sort of hunting uniform and when asked he quotes:

> Anybody who can blast his friend in the face and get him to take the rap for it is my kind of citizen.

Who's he supposed to be here?

Comment: Without really remembering the episode I would guess __[Dick Cheney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Cheney)__ and his infamous __[hunting accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Cheney_hunting_incident)__. - __Youtube Video:__ [Harry Whittington Apologizes for Getting Shot in the Face by Dick Cheney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILqnYx7XnwQ)

Comment: This question would be greatly improved with a screenshot of the costume in question.

Comment: @Oliver_C Right On!! I pulled up the transcript of the episode online and found Cheney name in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the ex Vice President of the United Stated, Dick Cheney.

One of his claims to fame was a shooting accident where he shot a fellow hunter in the face. There was was an alleged cover up of at least some of the details - all of which is covered its own [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Cheney_hunting_incident)